# Use of Cookies between two components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks, react-cookie

I have two Sidebar components. Both of them have a function that acts as a toggle.
What I want to do is the program initially starts with the Sidebar.js component.
The sidebar component's toggle property will be true by default.

Then, when I press the link to the processes page, the ProcessSidebar.js component is called there.
I want to save the isContentToggled value in the cookies in Sidebar.js, then read the isContentToggled value in ProcessSidebar.js and affect my Sidebar accordingly.

I want to do the opposite in the same way. I want to save the value of isContentToggled to cookies in ProcessSidebar.js, then read the value of isContentToggled in Sidebar.js and affect my Sidebar accordingly.

I put my code below.

**Sidebar.js**

`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';
    
    import profileImage from '../../../assets/img/profil.jpg';
    import iconImage from '../../../assets/img/icon.jpg';
    import businessManImage from '../../../assets/img/business-man-white.svg';
    import preferencessImage from '../../../assets/img/cogs-white.svg';
    import logoutImage from '../../../assets/img/logout.svg';
    import toggleImage from '../../../assets/img/toggle-icon.png';
    import profileWhite from '../../../assets/img/profile-white.svg';
    import classes from '../Sidebar/Sidebar.module.css';
    
    const Sidebar = props => {
      const [isContentToggled, setIsContentToggled] = useState(true);
      let url = ""
      return (
        <div>
          <div className={classes['side-bar']}>
            <div className={classes['side-bar-top']}>
              <div className={classes['side-bar-icon']}>
                <img src={iconImage} alt="profileresmi" />
              </div>
            </div>
    
    
            <div className={classes['side-bar-row']} style={{ height: '100px' }} >
              <div className={classes['side-bar-icons']} style={{ width: '100px' }} >
                <div className={classes['side-bar-profile-image']}>
                  <img src={profileImage} alt="profileresmi" />
                </div>
              </div>
              {isContentToggled && (
                <div className={classes['side-bar-profile-content']}>
                  <h3><b>Mert EKİNCİ</b></h3>
                  <h4>mert@akturk.de</h4>
                </div>
              )};
                    </div>
    
            <div className={classes['side-bar-row']}>
              <div className={classes['side-bar-icons']}>
                <a href={url} className={classes['side-bar-elements-icons']}>
                  <img src={businessManImage} alt="profileresmi" />
                </a>
              </div>
              {isContentToggled && (
                <div className={classes['side-bar-text']}>
                  <a href="/processes" class="active" >Processes</a>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
    
            <div style={{ clear: 'both' }} ></div>
            <div className={classes['side-bar-row']}>
              <div className={classes['side-bar-icons']}>
                <a href={url} className={classes['side-bar-elements-icons']}>
                  <img src={preferencessImage} alt="profileresmi" />
                </a>
              </div>
              {isContentToggled && (
                <div className={classes['side-bar-text']}>
                  <a href="/preferences" class="active">Preferences</a>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
    
            <div className={classes['side-bar-row']}>
              <div className={classes['side-bar-icons']}>
                <a href={url} className={classes['side-bar-elements-icons']}>
                  <img src={profileWhite} alt="profileresmi" />
                </a>
              </div>
              {isContentToggled && (
                <div className={classes['side-bar-text']}>
                  <a href="/profile" class="active">User</a>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
    
            <div className={classes['side-bar-row']}>
              <div className={classes['side-bar-icons']}>
                <a href={url} className={classes['side-bar-elements-icons']}>
                  <img src={logoutImage} alt="profileresmi" />
                </a>
              </div>
              {isContentToggled && (
                <div className={classes['side-bar-text']}>
                  <a href="/auth/login" class="active">Logout</a>
                </div>
              )}
            </div>
    
          </div>
          <div className={classes['side-toggle']}>
            <span onClick={() => setIsContentToggled(prevIsContentToggled => !prevIsContentToggled)
    
    
            } className={classes['side-bar-toggle']}>
              <img src={toggleImage} alt="profileresmi" />
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
    
      );
    }
    
    export default Sidebar;

`

**ProcessSidebar.js**


`

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useCookies } from 'react-cookie';

import iconImage from '../../../assets/img/icon.jpg';
import backArrowImage from '../../../assets/img/back-arrow.png';
import toggleImage from '../../../assets/img/toggle-icon.png';
import classes from '../Sidebar/Sidebar.module.css';

const ProcessSidebar = props => {
  const [isContentToggled, setIsContentToggled] = useState(true);
  let url = ""

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes['side-bar']}>
        <div className={classes['side-bar-top']}>
          <div className={classes['side-bar-icon']}>
            <img src={iconImage} alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className={classes['side-bar-row']} style={{ height: '70px', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <div className={classes['side-bar-icons']}>
            <a href={url} className={classes['side-bar-elements-icons']}>
              <div className={classes['back-arrow']}>
                <img src={backArrowImage} alt="" />
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
          {isContentToggled && (
            <div className={classes['side-bar-text']} style={{width : '200px', textAlign: 'center', marginLeft: '.5rem'}} >
              <a href="/" class="active">HOME PAGE</a>
            </div>
          )}

        </div>

        {isContentToggled && (<div id="process-list" className={classes['side-bar-text']}></div>
        )}


        <div className={classes['side-toggle']}>
          <span onClick={() => setIsContentToggled(prevIsContentToggled => !prevIsContentToggled)} className={classes['side-bar-toggle']}>
            <img src={toggleImage} alt="toggle" />
          </span>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
};


export default ProcessSidebar;
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using `useCookie` because you want to persist the variable value if the user refreshes the page if it's not the case then you may be using `useContext` for easily sharing the state between your two components.

Just utilize the `useEffect` hook to initialize the cookie if it isn't already and update it each time the user toggle the sidebar.

```js
const [isContentToggled, setIsContentToggled] = useState(true);
const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies(['sideBarToggleCookie']);

useEffect(() => {
  if (!cookies.sideBarToggleCookie)
    setCookie('sideBarToggleCookie', isContentToggled)
  else
    setIsContentToggled(cookies.sideBarToggleCookie)

  if (cookies.sideBarToggleCookie !== isContentToggled)
    setCookie('sideBarToggleCookie', isContentToggled)
}, [isContentToggled])
```

Also in the onClick just toggle the value like this then it will update the component and the useEffect will change the cookie value:

```
setIsContentToggled(!isContentToggled)
```

I didn't try the code but hope it will give you an idea on how to do it.